# Difference in meaning between "слышать, как ..." and "слышать, что ..."

Tags: значения

> Я не ослышалась? Клянусь, я только что слышала, **как** она поблагодарила меня.

I just heard this (sarcastically said) in conversation. I'm not sure why you use "как" instead of "что":

> Я не ослышалась? Клянусь, я только что слышала, **что** она поблагодарила меня.

Does this sound like you heard the news from someone else?

Comment: You may also stress "как" in the first phrase and thus get yet another meaning. That the specific way of thanking (words, intonations, gestures, etc) was contradicting the formal message of gratitude, was at very least not sincere if not intentionally provoking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

`слышала, что ...` means knowing of the fact

`слышала, как ...` means witnessing the fact

Comment: Is this "как" like "**when/as** she thanked me"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens rather without any conjuction at all ***i heard her thank me*** vs ***i heard that she'd thanked me***, but as *alexsms* notes ***что*** can also mean witnessing only that the emphasis is not on the content but on the fact, so a phrase with ***что*** refers to knowing of the fact irrespective of the way such knowledge is obtained, be it firsthand or through hearsay

Comment: Also, if a special stressing would be applied to "как" it would start meaning "как именно" and would have yet another meaning. "Oh, she thanked me, but I did hear how exactly she did it", meaning the very way of "thanking" was false, provoking, humiliating, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using ***как*** seems more dynamic to me.. I heard how she thanked me.. (I was hearing her, may be physically, very likely I heard it myself).

Using ***что*** is more about stating the fact, it could be *I heard that she thanked me* (I was there and heard it physically), but could also be that someone tells you about this fact (You've just heard from the person who had been near her that she had thanked you).

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант - с использованием "как" - звучит правильнее.

И да, действительно, вариант со словом "что" звучит, будто бы вы слышали это от другого человека. К тому же, повтор "что" в одном предложении не очень корректен.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with "как", because even a little stress on or a pause before "как" in "я слышала, как она поблагодарила меня" changes the meaning to "I know that she really does not care".  To avoid such misunderstandings and tautology (ослышалась-слышала) one could say "Я не ослышалась? Клянусь, она только что поблагодарила меня."